# Cross-domain cookies in IE 8 and 9 without an iframe?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, cross-domain

Suppose I control two domains, `www.api_domain.com` and `www.website_domain.com`. `www.api_domain.com` offers an API that requires the user to authenticate and then uses a session cookie to recognise the user who is making requests. `www.website_domain.com` loads a script onto its pages from `www.api_domain.com` and that script wants to make calls to API URLs on `www.api_domain.com` with the current user's cookie and use the results in some way on the page from `www.website_domain.com`.

For initially loading the script, or for any API URLs that don't require the user's session cookie to work, the easiest solution is simply to use an

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.website_domain.com
```

header on the response from `www.api_domain.com`. This seems to work out of the box on all browsers besides IE, and although IE won't respect the Allow-Origin header on AJAX requests made using jQuery's AJAX methods, there are libraries like xdr.js which do some magic behind the scenes to make jQuery, IE and the Allow-Origin header play nice together and behave like in all other browsers (I don't know the details of what xdr.js does, but it works perfectly for non-credentialed requests as far as I can see).

The problem comes when I want to hit a URL on `http://www.api_domain.com` that requires the user's session cookie. When this problem is discussed in a browser-agnostic setting, two solutions are usually proposed:

1. Use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the response from
   to make cookies be sent even with cross-domain requests.
2. Create an iframe on the page on `http://www.website_domain.com` with origin
   `http://www.api_domain.com`, have the two windows communicate with
   each other using [HTML5 post messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) and delegate all
   responsibility for making requests to `http://www.api_domain.com` to
   the iframe.

I would greatly prefer to use option 1 if possible, since it lets you write your Javascript code to use the API on `http://www.api_domain.com` in the same way that you would write it to touch a same-domain API. To use the iframe approach, we'd need to learn or create some framework for sending AJAX-like requests to the iframe, with success and error handlers. It also means we need to create the code to be loaded into the iframe, which will just be a whole chunk of thin wrappers for hitting the API URLs. It just seems uglier, trickier, and harder to understand than the first approach.

However, I can't figure out how to make option 1 work on IE. I'm setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on my API URLs, and all other browsers send cookies to those URLs, but IE 9 doesn't, even with the xdr.js library. (I haven't tested on IE 8.) There are no other symptoms to report whatsoever. I can see the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` headers in the responses from `www.api_domain.com` when I view them in IE's developer tools, but there are no cookie headers in the request.

Is there some hack or magical incantation that I can use to make Internet Explorer respect the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header, or some other header I can use that IE recognises?

Comment: Does setting p3p privacy policy help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666376/copying-cookies-cross-domain-why-is-ie-blocking-cookies-other-browsers-are-send?rq=1

Comment: @flup Nope, it's totally irrelevant to this.

Comment: As an aside that does not help answer this question but is likely to be useful to anyone reading it: rather than crafting your own proxy iframe, considering using [this library](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain/). I haven't tested it, but it looks like it should transparently do all the work of proxying cross-domain AJAX traffic via post message for you. Unless you additionally need supercookie support to handle the growing number of browsers that block 'third party' cookies by default (including ones set in iframes), it should be adequate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option 1 is not possible in IE9 or below because there is no support for CORS using the XMLHttpRequest. Additionally, if you try to use XDomainRequest, you will never be able to send any cookies along with your request. I've been down this road several times working on writing a ui testing library to be used with testswarm. What you want to do is just not possible in that manner.

Here is a post by Eric Law, an ex-Microsoft developer, discussing the issue in detail:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

The relevant sections, which make clear that sending cookies with a CORS request is impossible in IE 8 and 9, are as follows:

> In Internet Explorer 8, the XDomainRequest object was introduced. This object allows AJAX applications to make safe cross-origin requests directly by ensuring that HTTP Responses can only be read by the current page if the data source indicates that the response is public; in that way, the Same Origin Policy security guarantee is protected. Responses indicate their willingness to allow cross domain access by including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP response header with value *, or the exact origin of the calling page.
>
> When designing the new object, ensuring that existing sites and services would not be put at risk was our top priority. To that end, we imposed a number of restrictions on what sort of requests can be made with the XDomainRequest object.
>
> ...
>
> 5: No authentication or cookies will be sent with the request
>
> In order to prevent misuse of the user’s ambient authority (e.g. cookies, HTTP credentials, client certificates, etc), the request will be stripped of cookies and credentials and will ignore any authentication challenges or Set-Cookie directives in the HTTP response. XDomainRequests will not be sent on previously-authenticated connections, because some Windows authentication protocols  (e.g. NTLM/Kerberos) are per-connection-based rather than per-request-based.
>
> Sites that wish to perform authentication of the user for cross-origin requests can use explicit methods (e.g. tokens in the POST body or URL) to pass this authentication information without risking the user’s ambient authority.

Now assuming you control both locations, you could presumably create a server to server authentication process and go about passing a session id of sorts provided from the domain, for the other domain, of which the client is actually on through your request. It's not pretty, but it works. This method is also mentioned in the article. You will want to be careful though because it opens up the possibility for session hijacking.

Comment: Awesome link, thank you. Makes clear that this is not possible. Server-to-server auth seems like an even clunkier solution than using an iframe, so I'll stick with the iframe solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

IE8+ has an alternative to `XMLHttpRequest` thats supports credentials which is `XDomainRequest`. anyway, `XDomainRequest` is not implemented by JQuery because it has less functionality than that are provided by `XMLHttpRequest`, but there is plugin like [jQuery CORS Plugin](https://github.com/Ovea/cors) that provide what you need.

> jQuery plugin which transparently adds Cross Origin Resource Sharing
>   (CORS) amongst browsers, including IE8+, to allow cross-domain Ajax
>   requests with cookies and headers support.

also i think but not sure that IE doesn't support wildcards in headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: We're not using wildcards; you can't use wildcards with credentialed requests in any browsers I've seen anyway, as per the CORS spec. The github repo you've linked to looks promising, but I'm a little confused. There's both Java and Javascript there, and no usage instructions; is the idea that that the Javascript only works in conjunction with the Java stuff being used serverside somehow to handle requests?

Comment: actually i didn't give it a try yet, i think the java is just for server side testing. you could check this too https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest